# Highchart - hide name in legend if no data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

This is a little specific situation, I need to compare ITEMS and show the result in a chart. User enters two or three or four article ID and gets data in chart. 
Problem is when user enters only two or three articles ID, then in chart legend, I still get a name for line without data.

```
$scope.chartConfig1 = getChartConfigWithYaxisPlotLines('Production');
            $scope.chartConfig1.series.push({
                id: 1,
                name: "Item " + firstId,
                data: $scope.data[0],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: "Item  " + firstId,
                color: "#1ea775",
                data: $scope.data[1],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }, {
                id: 3,
                name: "Item  " + firstId,
                data: $scope.data[2],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }, {
                id: 4,
                name: "Item " + firstId,
                data: $scope.data[3],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            },{
                id: 5,
                name: "Item " + secondId,
                data: $scope.data[4],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }, {
                id: 6,
                name: "Item " + secondId,
                data: $scope.data[5],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }, {
                id: 7,
                name: "Item " + secondId,
                data: $scope.data[6],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }, {
                id: 8,
                name: "Item " + secondId,
                data: $scope.data[7],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            },{
                id: 9,
                name: "Item " + thirdId,
                data: $scope.data[8],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }, {
                id: 10,
                name: "Item " + thirdId,
                data: $scope.data[9],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }, {
                id: 11,
                name: "Item " + thirdId,
                data: $scope.data[10],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }, {
                id: 12,
                name: "Item " + thirdId,
                data: $scope.data[11],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }
            );
```

In legend, I show Item and article ID (passed in function when submitting input ID for compare), and if we compare only two article, in legend we get Item 1, Item 2, Item undefined, Item undefined. If enter all four input everything is fine
[image]

Is there any way in highchart to hide name in legend if data is null or undefined? Thnx

Comment: I would do this on the data end, before sending it to the chart - only build the series object for series that have data, and there won't be any empty series to show in the legend.

Comment: This is a way I try to do before ask here, but this is very complex part of the app. Here I have 6 more charts in the same way, and on one click on compare button, I call sixteen different URL and push it to data. For all 7 charts, we push data to same $scope.data. And If I check if the value is NULL or UNDEFINED before sending to chart, and if some value is undefined then my $scope.data[0] or any other change place in array and I get wrong data. I rly need to find a solution for hiding data directly in "series.push"

Comment: So set up a loop instead of pushing a static series object. Loop through `$scope.data`, and if there is no data for a given node, don't push it.

Comment: i will try. thnx

Comment: Check if you can override function to render legend or not. I have done similar stuff with nvd3. so there should be way to overider it.

Comment: @Arter Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788558/highcarts-custom-legend

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `load` event to examine series in a loop and hide the ones without any data:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        this.series.forEach(function(s) {
          s.update({
            showInLegend: s.points.length
          });
        });
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [1, 2]
  }, {
    data: [3, 4, 2]
  }, {
    data: [] // no data
  }]
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/355u0kaw/

---

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.showInLegend
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render